# Nginx setup for local webapp and websocket

Tags: linux, tomcat, nginx

following is my nginx configuration,

```
server { //PART-1   
        listen 80;
        server_name _;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_pass_request_headers on;

                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade  $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection Upgrade;
            }
        }

server { //PART-2
        listen 80;
        server_name service;
        root /usr/local/tomcat7/webapps/service-snapshot;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/ServiceUI/;
                }
        }
```

first part of config works fine for websockets, which I am already using. 
Second part of config is for webapp running on Apache tomcat 7.0.56, which is not working.

Is there something wrong with config? assuming `server_name` in both parts might be causing issue!
Any suggestions!

Comment: what exactly do you mean by saying "not working".. is there any error message in the logs or displayed?

Comment: it's connecting to the websockets, not the webapp! no logs!

Comment: add this line to the second server block: `error_log                   /var/log/nginx/webapp-error.log;`, restart nginx, try to browse the webapp site and look what's written into webapp-error.log

Comment: I see this in Nginx access logs `GET /Service/ HTTP/1.1" 404`. But I am sure service is running!

Comment: oh I see... that's not how it's done.. I'll post an answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While having multiple services on one IP and port is working perfectly fine, the `server_name` directive is using the HOST header submitted by the client/browser. In this case, you're not supplying the header but instead asking for a specific location on the same server (you're not asking for `http://_` or `http://service` but for `http://yourserver/services` from what I see in the comments).

To make it work, you have to specify the different services via `location`s like this:

```
server { 
    listen 80;
    server_name THIS_IS_WHERE_YOUR_DOMAIN_OR_MAYBE_LOCALHOST_GOES;
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass_request_headers on;

            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade  $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection Upgrade;
    }


    location /Service {

            root /usr/local/tomcat7/webapps/service-snapshot;

            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/ServiceUI/;
            }
    }
```